# How can I keep mobs from being too close together with /spreadplayers and /execute?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to summon multiple Slimes, then make sure that they are never in the same block. (If it's not possible to keep them from being in the same block, having them be at least 1 block from each other would work too.)

To do this I tried nesting execute commands like this:

```
execute @e[type=Slime,name=explore1] ~ ~ ~ execute @e[type=Slime,name=explore1,r=0,c=1] ~ ~ ~ spreadplayers ~.5 ~.5 0 1 false @e[type=Slime,name=explore1,r=1,c=1]
```

But that didn't work. I also tried

```
execute @e[type=Slime,name=explore1] ~ ~ ~ spreadplayers ~.5 ~.5 0 1 false @e[type=Slime,name=explore1,c=1,r=0]
```

I figured the `r=0` tag might be off but I also tried with `r=1` and it still didn't work.

The first command groups all the Slimes together and randomly teleports them, and the second command just does nothing.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The following command should work:

```
execute @e[type=Slime,name=explore1] ~ ~ ~ spreadplayers ~ ~ 2 3 false @e[type=Slime,rm=0,r=1,name=explore1]
```

All slimes will try to spread nearby (`r=1`) slimes that aren't themselves (`rm=0`) a maximum of 3 blocks around them.

Comment: Just be aware that `rm=0` will not be able to target entities at the exact same coordinates as the slime, so if two are at the same location then they will not be targeted. `/spreadplayers` itself can end up placing slimes at the same location.

Comment: @Skylinerw Yep, when I was testing it though it didn't seem an issue in practice, as the slimes immediately push each other apart slightly then get teleported (though it could be a problem if OP has them with NoAI).

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't working for me @colorfusion, the slimes never stop being spread around... I _was_ using `NoAI` but it still doesn't work with it off.

Comment: Update: It works with `NoAI` off and `rm=1` + `r=2` in the last command, but that's not completely ideal; I really need the slimes to have `NoAI`. Any ideas?

Comment: @A.J.Ruckman Do you need to constantly check if slimes are on top of each other, or just when you summon/manually move them? There's another possible solution either way, but which one works best depends on what you're actually using the slimes for (why do they need to be never close together?).

Comment: @colorfusion I want to 'fill' an area with slimes, so I don't really need to do it constantly, but probably for 30 seconds at least.